# Capitalization guidelines for Salesforce objects in managed package application UI

Tags: sobject, ui, style

Can anyone suggest guidelines for how to capitalise references to Salesforce objects in a managed package application UI, in particular standard objects like Account, Contact etc.?

I've read the [Salesforce Style Guide for Documentation and User Interface Text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_pubs_style_guide.meta/salesforce_pubs_style_guide/style_capitalization.htm) which does not cover this thoroughly but has some relevant points:

> Capitalize the names of all tabs in the application. Refer to them
>   using the exact spelling in the user interface. For example: Accounts
>   tab, not Account tab...
>
> ...However, don't change the capitalization of objects, methods, calls,
>   or other language constructs, such as the Account object

So the guide capitalises all references to Salesforce objects. However if you look within the standard Salesforce UI, the capitalisation varies:

> A Sales Process contains the Stages an **Opportunity** follows through its
>   sales cycle.
>
> This feature allows a user to search for **opportunities** that share
>   common fields with the user's **opportunity**.
>
> This page allows you to specify the fields that can appear on the
>   **Account** page.
>
> Customize fields on the **accounts** page
>
> Define the Apex triggers for **Contacts** here.

The motivation is to ensure a clean and consistent style within a Salesforce application that makes frequent references to standard Salesforce objects. At the moment we have a bit of a mish-mash where the capitalisation in each UI element mostly depends on developer preference.

Comment: Coding style? UI labels that refer to the standard objects? Both?